# Android studio emulator isn't showing the colors properly

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

The Android studio emulator is not showing the colors specified properly, instead its showing the color lighter then the original color. But if I run it in a physical device , then the color is properly shown.

This is an screenshot for comparison between my emulator color and the original color  https://ibb.co/tm2sGps

This is the code i used

```
body: Container(
  color: Color(0xff0a0e21),
  )
```

Help me with this issue.

Comment: Do not post your code as a screenshot. Instead [edit] the question post [mcve] here.

Comment: Please replace the link to your code screenshot with an actual example of the code here on the site (use the "Code" or "Snippet" style tool in the editor). That way, not only can users here copy the code to reproduce the bug on their own, but others can also find similar issues in the future. Good luck!

Comment: what if its' due to brightness variations  ?

Answer (score 2):

Just try changing your alpha opacity from "ff" to "00" to your color code.

```
body: Container(
      color: Color(0x000a0e21),
      )
```